# Serving a directory of static content (images, svg, etc..) from with Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I have the following folder structure with CSS, JS, and static assets:

```
- app/
  - frontend/

    - javascript/
      - application.js
      - (other various .js, .jsx files)

    - stylesheets/
      - application.scss
      - (other various .css, .scss files)

    - images/
      - (various png, jpg, svg, etc.. files)
```

I have webpack configured to bundle JS + CSS as follows:

```
'entry': {
  'application': ['app/javascript/application.js', 'app/stylesheets/application.scss']
},
'output': {
  'filename': '[name]-[hash].js',
  'chunkFilename': '[name]-[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  'path': /public/packs,
  'publicPath': '/packs/',
  'pathinfo': true
},
'module': {
  'strictExportPresence': true,
  'rules': [
    {
      'test': /\.(css)$/iu,
      'use': [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      'test': /\.(scss|sass)$/iu,
      'use': [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },

    {
      'test': /\.(js|jsx)?(\.erb)?$/u,
      'exclude': /node_modules/u,
      'use': ['babel-loader']
    }
  ]
},
```

How do I do the same with all my static images? I'm struggling with the following:

1. What is the "entry point" for my image assets? JS and CSS have a clear entry point (`application.js`, `application.scss`) but there's no equivalent for images
2. I looked into [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) but it seems to only build assets that are `@import`-ed from some javascript. It doesn't blindly build all my assets.
3. Is webpack even meant to handle this? Should i just write a separate task to move my assets to the `public/` folder manually? I'd like to avoid that since it wouldn't work with webpack dev server locally.

Thanks!

Comment: use copywebpack plugin as explained : https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/copy-all-images-files-to-a-folder-using-copy-webpack-plugin-7c8cf2de7676

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Rowntree's suggestion of using `CopyWebpackPlugin` worked great.

Here's the full webpack config i used. The main difference from the version posted in the question is the addition of the new `plugin` at the bottom.

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  'entry': {
    'application': ['app/javascript/application.js', 'app/stylesheets/application.scss']
  },
  'output': {
    'filename': '[name]-[hash].js',
    'chunkFilename': '[name]-[chunkhash].chunk.js',
    'path': /public/packs,
    'publicPath': '/packs/',
    'pathinfo': true
  },
  'module': {
    'strictExportPresence': true,
    'rules': [
      {
        'test': /\.(css)$/iu,
        'use': [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        'test': /\.(scss|sass)$/iu,
        'use': [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },

      {
        'test': /\.(js|jsx)?(\.erb)?$/u,
        'exclude': /node_modules/u,
        'use': ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  'plugins': [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        'from': '**/*',
        'context': `app/frontend/images`,
        'to': '/some/public/output/dir'
      }
    ])
  ]
}

module.exports = config;
```